# Is taxonomy a good choice for managing Code Lists, instead of creating tables of their own?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have a project where there is a set of code lists (code/label), Airport codes for example.

I am hesitating between creating my own tables, with two columns code/label and using Taxonomy (fieldable \o/ )
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

Since there isn't anything common between codes and labels, I think you should create your own table.

Also see [How to Decide Between Using Taxonomy Terms and a CCK Field](http://www.juliakm.com/how-decide-between-using-taxonomy-terms-and-cck-field-classify-content-drupal-site)

Comment: Thabks for your answer Hamid. What do you mean by nothing in common between codes and labels ?